# jQuery check how many select elements have selectedIndex !== 0

Tags: jquery, html-select, selectedindex

I have multiple select elements in my page and I need to find out how many of the elements do have a selectedIndex !== 0

```
<select name="startMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1" selected>Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="4">Opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="startYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3">Opt3</option>
 </select>

<select name="endMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3" selected>Opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="endYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3">Opt3</option>
</select>
```

I tried filter and localStorage Objects on Change, but no succes....
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you add what you tried and why that was not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this within the jquery selector directly:

```
$(".selCalendar option[value!='']:selected")
```

Example:

```js
$("#click").click(function() {

  var chosen = $(".selCalendar option[value!='']:selected");

  console.log(chosen.length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="startMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1" selected>Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="4">Opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="startYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3">Opt3</option>
 </select>

<select name="endMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3" selected>Opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="endYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3">Opt3</option>
</select>

<button type='button' id='click'>count</button>
```

---

Or you can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/%20filter) with a callback on the selects:

```
$(".selCalendar").filter(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).val() !== "";
});
```

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  var chosen = $(".selCalendar").filter(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).val() !== "";
  });

  console.log(chosen.length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="startMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1" selected>Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="4">Opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="startYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3">Opt3</option>
 </select>

<select name="endMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3" selected>Opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="endYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="1">Opt1</option>
 <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 <option value="3">Opt3</option>
</select>

<button type='button' id='click'>count</button>
```

Comment: I don't have any button here to click, I will analyze the length on select change. So your first sample was not a perfect fit.
But I was able to use your filter sample, which is short AND smart. Thank you for spending time on this, really helpful.

Comment: The button is only there to provide a re-usable working snippet (ie you can see how it's affected as you change the select values).  Could have used .change instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why complicate things, simply loop for empty value.

```
var $selects = $('select');
var nonEmptyValCount = 0;

$selects.each( function (index, el) {
    if (el.value !== '') nonEmptyValCount ++;
})

//output
console.log(nonEmptyValCount );
```

Comment: I was thinking in that direction before, and although it will work I like freedomn-m 's filter solution best, as this is pretty smart and short.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this :

```
var savedArray = new Array({ name: "startMonth", value: 1 }, { name: "startYear", value: 0 }, { name: "endMonth", value: 3 }, { name: "endYear", value: 0 });

$('#startMonth, #startYear, #endMonth, #endYear').change((ev) => {
    var index = savedArray.findIndex((elem) => { return elem.name == ev.target.id });
    savedArray[index].value = ev.target.val();
});

const countZero = () => {
  let count = 0;
  savedArray.forEach((elem) => {
      count += elem.value == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  });
  return count;
};
```

I did not try my code above. To make it work you just have to add ID to your selects.

Comment: # is for Id not for name.. use a common class for all select box

Comment: No with id we can get `ev.target.id` and edit `savedArray` as much as we wan't.